# Get next sunday for given date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table in MYSQL with date represented as a string in my column.

```
Example: 20190828 represents 28th Aug 2019
```

Now I want to get the next sunday for this given date, if the given date is already a sunday then no changes needed. Also how to get the end of the month for the given date.

```
Example:

For input - 20190828, next sunday is 20190901, end of the month is 20190831
```

Comment: Why in the world would you not use a date type column? It would make everything so much easier.

Comment: To get last day of the month, use [LAST_DAY()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_day.asp) , and to get day you can use either [DAY_OF_WEEK()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_dayofweek.asp) or [WEEKDAY()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_weekday.asp). To change datestring, use [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the string to a date, then do arithemetics:

```
select
    mydate,
    str_to_date(mydate, '%Y%m%d') + interval 6 - weekday(str_to_date(mydate, '%Y%m%d')) day next_sunday
    last_day(str_to_date(mydate, '%Y%m%d')) last_day_of_the_month
from mytable
```

Actually the casting may not even be necessary, since MySQL should implicitly convert the strings to date here:

```
select
    mydate,
    mydate + interval 6 - weekday(mydate) day next_sunday,
    last_day(mydate) last_day_of_the_month
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=35f546c3a841e2b46f3a7018ff21547f)**:

```
with mytable as (select '20190828' mydate union all select '20200327')
select
    mydate,
    mydate + interval 6 - weekday(mydate) day next_sunday,
    last_day(mydate) last_day_of_the_month
from mytable
```

```
mydate   | next_sunday | last_day_of_the_month
:------- | :---------- | :--------------------
20190828 | 2019-09-01  | 2019-08-31           
20200327 | 2020-03-29  | 2020-03-31
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain how the logic for next sunday is calculated? `    mydate + interval 6 - weekday(mydate) day next_sunday,`

Comment: `weekday(mydate)` gives you the day of the week for `mydate` ; `6` is the day of the week for Sunday, so that's arithmetics.